# Limit sub-user access to specific filters on same form

Tags: cognito-forms

We are using one form to collect data for the entire company, but certain departments only need to see some of the entries that meet a specific criteria. We have set up a filter, but they are still able to access all of the other entries for the form.

Would it be possible to limit 'sub users' (Editors and Reviewers using the same form) to only be able to view the records that match certain filters that are set up?

Answer (score 0):

[Saved entry views](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/entry-management) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) allow you to quickly filter, sort and view the fields you want.  Currently, permissions are assigned on a per form basis, not to individual saved entry views.

While view-specific permissions may be supported in the future, the best way to handle this right now is to copy your form for each department and [assign permissions](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/164/account--organizations/user-management/user-permission-levels) accordingly.  This allows you to create one form with all of the fields, emails, and entry views you want, and then replicate this easily.

We use this approach for job applications, creating a new form for each new position we post.  This makes it easier to assign permissions and make minor customizations specific to the position being posted.  Also, our upcoming support for [form folders](https://trello.com/c/z2vJRXuG/177-form-folders) will make it easy to manage your forms by department or type of form.